# Sharing Power Apps form which act as a Survey to internal and external users

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, powerapp, external-sharing, guest-access

We have the following requirements/environment:

1. SharePoint Online
2. We need to build an App, where Power Apps is one option, where we will build a list of questions and share it with external users to get their replies/feedback.

So we are planning to build the following:

1. Create a SharePoint site  >> allow external sharing on it.
2. Add a custom list >> customize the List forms using Power Apps and build the survey. we go with this approach as customizing SharePoint list forms using Power Apps does not require the external users to have additional licenses, unlike using Standalone app.
3. So we will be creating Guest accounts inside azure >> and share the SharePoint list with the external users so they can access the Power App.

So is our approach accurate? or we can implement our requirements in a better way?

Comment: This approach should work. Make sure to create a group for external users & grant necessary permissions(maybe contribute) on list/site to this group.

Comment: Yes, this approach works. However, as mentioned on your other question, Microsoft Forms is likely a better platform for this as that's one of its primary functions.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**. The approach you are planning should work as guest users do not require the additional license to use power apps customized list forms.

**Microsoft documentation**: [What license must be assigned to my guest so they can run an app shared with them?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/share-app-guests#what-license-must-be-assigned-to-my-guest-so-they-can-run-an-app-shared-with-them)

**Similar thread**: [Power Apps and External Users](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Power-Apps-and-External-Users/m-p/1455988/highlight/true#M377664)